# What is the pythonic way of generating an oAuth token?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oauth-2.0

For this example I will use shipstation's [api](https://www.shipstation.com/developer-api/#/introduction/shipstation-api-requirements/authentication), but this question applies to any api using oAuth tokens.

> The ShipStation API uses Basic HTTP authentication. The Authorization header is constructed as follows:
>
> - Username (`API_KEY`) and password (`API_SECRET`) are combined into a string "username:password"
> - The resulting string is then encoded using the RFC2045-MIME variant of Base64, except not limited to 76 char/line
> - The authorization method and a space i.e. "Basic " is then put before the encoded string.
>
> For example, if the `API_KEY` given is 'ShipStation' and the `API_SECRET` is 'Rocks' then the header is formed as follows:
>
> Authorization: Basic U2hpcFN0YXRpb246Um9ja3M=

Easy right?  My first attempt:

```
import base64
KEY = 'ShipStation'
SECRET = 'Rocks'

AUTH = bytes(str(KEY) + ':' + str(SECRET), encoding='utf-8')
TOKEN = base64.b64encode(AUTH)

AUTH_TOKEN = 'Basic ' + str(TOKEN)
print(AUTH_TOKEN) # Basic b'U2hpcFN0YXRpb246Um9ja3M='
```

As you can see, the `AUTH_TOKEN` I made has an additional `b'` at the beginning and `'` at the end, which causes a 401 when you send the request.

Here is my fix to this:

```
import base64
KEY = 'ShipStation'
SECRET = 'Rocks'

AUTH = bytes(str(KEY) + ':' + str(SECRET), encoding='utf-8')
TOKEN = str(base64.b64encode(AUTH))

AUTH_TOKEN = 'Basic ' + TOKEN[2:len(TOKEN)-1]
print(AUTH_TOKEN) # Basic U2hpcFN0YXRpb246Um9ja3M=
```

While the above code works, this is clearly not the way it was intended to be done. (I assume?)

### TLDR;

What is the *pythonic* way of turning the `TOKEN` in the example above into the proper format?